# Android Studio Checkout Github Error "CreateProcess=2" (Windows)

Tags: github, android-studio

Today I've tried to checkout my Github project using brand new Android Studio and ended up with this nasty error :

[image]

Why things just never work out of the box ...?

Comment: "Why things just never work out of the box ...?"

Because they carefully pointed out that this software is still in its early stages, and that things might not always be working properly. Ref. Google I/O 2013.

Comment: I actually really second that "why things..." comment. Java is out since ages now and I still have to add environment variables here and there. Boring!

Comment: And guess what? It's mid 2016 and I'm still struggling with same error.

Answer (score 234, accepted):

I've solved the problem , and I will explain how :

1. Download [Github For Windows](http://windows.github.com/) client and install it.
2. After The client successfully installed , connect it with your github account.It should be easy , just follow the wizard.
3. Then you should add git.exe location to your ["Path Variable"](http://java.com/en/download/help/path.xml). The location you should add will probably be something like :
   **C:\Users\Your_Username\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_ca477551eeb4aea0e4ae9fcd3358bd96720bb5c8\bin**

Alternatively , if you don't want to add to environment variables. You can open the android studio and go to :
Settings -> Version Control -> Git
In text box next to "Path to Git Executable" you will see "git.exe" , just give it a full path like so :
**C:\Users\Your_Username\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_ca477551eeb4aea0e4ae9fcd3358bd96720bb5c8\bin\git.exe**

**EDIT :**
For latest Github for windows versions some can find the git.exe under ***"...\cmd\git.exe"*** rather than ***"...\bin\git.exe"***.

Comment: For client you can use http://msysgit.github.io and use path which you specified in installation instead C:\Users\Your_Username\AppData\....

Comment: RESTART YOUR IDE , after you've set up PATH variable .

Comment: couldn't find git.exe forever, thank you so much. You can also just set up the git path in Android Studio settings so you don't have to global path in windows and restart

Comment: There is no option in the git install wizard to sign into my account and every time I open the git gui i asks me if I want to do this http://matthew-brett.github.io/pydagogue/git_gui_windows.html#working-from-another-machine and I'm pretty sure this only works if I have a copy on my local machine already.. whether I do or don't this isn't what I want to do. I guess my question is is how do I sign into my github?

Comment: my git.exe was in cmd\ not bin\

Comment: now path of git.exe is in "C:\Users\Jacobmathew\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_c7e0cbde92ba5652k956jd63hfj7a62jf8j4f8js92n3n53n32\mingw32\bin\git.exe" ( OR ) "C:\Users\Jacobmathew\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_c7e0cbde92ba5652k956jd63hfj7a62jf8j4f8js92n3n53n32\cmd\git.exe"

Comment: I made the mistake of using C:\Users\...\cmd\git.exe for the Path variable, but **the Path variable should just be the directory**, and not include the _git.exe_.

Comment: I already have GitHub for Windows installed and have been using it from the command line with my Eclipse projects.  So now that I'm moving to Android Studio it was very helpful to learn that this can work fine with Android Studio as well.  I'm planning to keep my Eclipse installation with all git archives intact and start fresh in Android Studio because (it seems to me) it would not make sense to go back to a commit that used the Eclipse folder hierarchy inside Android Studio, which has a different hierarchy.

Comment: Using the latest git as at 11 june 2018 use :: C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\app-1.2.3\resources\app\git\cmd\git.exe

Answer (score 59):

I found what I think is a faster solution.
Install Git for Windows from *here*: http://git-scm.com/download/win

That automatically adds its path to the system variable during installation *if you tell the installer to do so* (it asks for that). So you don't have to edit anything manually.

Just close and restart Android Studio if it's open and you're ready to go.

[image: wizard sample]

Comment: This is also a much smaller download than GitHub for Windows. If your main goal is to integrate with Android Studio, this answer makes more sense to me.

Comment: Worked for me on `Windows 10`

Comment: Worked for me on `Windows 7`

Comment: There wasn't too much of a size difference (110mb vs 180mb) but you do have control of where git is installed whereas github dumps to appdata. Precious SSD space!

Comment: My system is windows 10. Still I am facing same problem i.e. git.exe not found.

Comment: I have checked  in program files in git directory but could not find git.exe.

Comment: Android Studio restart helped for me

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me(in Windows10). Very quick solution.

Answer (score 8):

I am using Windows 10 OS and **GitHub Desktop** version 1.0.9.

For the new **Github For Windows**, **git.exe** is present in the below location.

```
%LOCALAPPDATA%\GitHubDesktop\app-[gitdesktop-version]\resources\app\git\cmd\git.exe
```

**Example:**

```
%LOCALAPPDATA%\GitHubDesktop\app-1.0.9\resources\app\git\cmd
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have downloaded `Github Desktop Client 1.0.9` then the path for `git.exe` will be

> **C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\app-1.0.9\resources\app\git\cmd\git.exe**

Answer (score 2):

I faced same issue in android studio 3.2.1, solved the issue by **setting git path in System Environment variable**

> C:\Program Files\Git\bin\,C:\Program Files\Git\bin\

And I imported the project once again and solved the issue!!!

Note :  Check your android studio git settings has properly set the correct path to git.exe

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Steps:

1) Download git for windows https://git-scm.com/downloads

2) Install downloaded git with default setup

3) From Android Studio close if any project is open then Click on Configure -> Settings -> Version Control -> Git

> 4) Change Path to Git executable : **git.exe** to **C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe**

5) Apply and Ok

6) Try to clone from Check out project from Version Control

7) Done

[image]

Answer (score 0):

for Android Studio 3.0.1, you can config GitHub path for following path:

1. File > Setting > Version Control
2. List item
3. Click "+" on the top-right conor to open "Add VCS Directory Mapping"
4. Click "Configure VCS" to open "Version Control Configurations"
5. Click "Git" then you'll see Path to Git executable]
6. Input : C:\Users[you user name]\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_d7effa1a4a322478cd29c826b52a0c118ad3db11\cmd\git.exe
7. Test it

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6vHj.png)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar error with RubyMine 2016.3 recently, wherein any attempts at checkout or export to Github were met with "Cannot run program 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.exe': CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified"

As an alternative solution for this problem, other than editing the Path system variable, you can try searching through the program files of Android Studio for a git.xml file and editing the myPathToGit option to match the actual location of git.exe on your computer. This is how I fixed this similar issue in RubyMine.

Posting this solution here for the sake of posterity.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue on Mac.  I simply quit Android Studio and restarted it, and for some reason had no further issues.