# Error running git"Cannot run program "git": error=2

Tags: android, github, project, clone

[image: http://www.subirimagenes.net/i/131230100130372529.png]

I have this error on my Android Studio running with Mac OS 10.8.3, I've installed the github client but is not necesary...

Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the path registered in `Settings -> Version Control -> Git`, in text box next to "`Path to Git Executable`".

It should reference a local installation of git.
If the path mentioned there doesn't exist, that would explain the error message.

Comment: There is a similar case (for Windows) at http://stackoverflow.com/a/16614411/6309

Comment: The box next you commnet is in eclipse, i dont have idea where is the path of git in mac os x

Comment: @user3145838 simply install your own git (http://git-scm.com/book/en/Getting-Started-Installing-Git#Installing-on-Mac), and reference that path.

Answer (score 5):

Within terminal you can find your git install directory with:

```
git --exec-path
```

Answer (score 4):

Use your terminal and check the following.

1) Check if you have installed git

```
git --version
```

You should see something like

```
git version 1.7.9.5
```

If not, there could be an error in Git installation

2) See if a `.git` file exists in the directory you want to push to the remote repo.

```
cd <into your directory>
ls -altr
```

You should see a file with the name `.git`.

This is the file that git will use to track the repo details.