# Gradle Palantir git-version installs but fails to load at build time

Tags: git, gradle, plugins, versioning

I've built a multi-project build.gradle script that uses the Plantir git-version plugin 0.8.0.
The plugin loads using the following syntax:

```
plugins {
  id "com.palantir.git-version" version "0.8.0"
}
```

I can also retrieve git version information using the following lines:

```
version gitVersion()
def details = versionDetails()
```

However, when another developer tries to run the build on their machine, the version gitVersion() fails with an error complaining that it cannot find gitVersion().  I have verfied that git-version 0.8.0 downloaded and installed from the git command line and that a git-version.jar file gets built in the user's .gradle cache directory.  Is there some way to debug load and run of a plugin?  Another developer machine can't even get past the load of the plugin.  I do have

```
repositories{
  jcenter()
}
```

in the build script so it should not be having problems with either download, install (.jar), or run.

Comment: what does `./gradlew printVersion --debug` print out on the other dev's machine?

Comment: Here's an extract of the output of ./gradlew printVersion --debug
`FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
Build file 'C:\Dev\git\company\gradle\build.gradle' line: 14
12:28:26.300 [ERROR] * What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'gradle'.
> Cannot run program "git": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified`

Comment: Line 14 is the reference to the palantir plugin.  Since the build normally executes via eclipse, command line git is not normally used.  eGit and Buildship automatically take care of problems with git and gradle plugins.  The thing that is somewhat interesting about this problem is the fact that this is a Windows 10 user with a Microsoft managed account.  The user's home directory on the file system is user.COMP-NT.  I have noticed problems in the past with gradle not liking spaces in a username.  It would not surprise me if it also does not like dots and dashes in home directories.

Comment: for the error you showed, probably related to git installation then, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20836338/error-running-gitcannot-run-program-git-error-2, also, can you attach the error message to question itself?

Comment: The solution was to run gradle from the command line.  This caused gradle to download palantir plugins in the user's .gradle repository.  Buildship on Windows Eclipse appears to have some subtle bugs that can be bypassed by installing the gradle command line tool.