# How to open a GitHub project in Android Studio?

Tags: android, github, android-studio

I have just downloaded a project from GitHub, but I don't know how to open it in Android Studio. I tried to use *check out projects from version control*, but it shows an error message:

> cannot run program "get.exe":create process=2, the system cannot find
>   the file specified

Comment: Use import project and select the folder the app is in

Comment: kindly post your logs, BTW it can be opened by File->New->Import Project-> select the project's root directory

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when I first started integrating GitHub with my Android Studio Projects. This solved my problem, please reference this stack answer

[Android Studio Checkout Github Error “CreateProcess=2” (Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16614410/android-studio-checkout-github-error-createprocess-2-windows)

You need to set the environment variable in Android Studio
**C:\Users\Your_Username\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_ca477551eeb4aea0e4ae9fcd3358bd96720bb5c8\bin\git.exe**

> You can open the android studio and go to : Settings -> Version Control -> Git In text box next to "Path to Git Executable" you will see "git.exe" , just give it a full path