# Cannot execute Git commands from Gradle build script on Windows 10

Tags: windows, git, gradle, wrapper, minecraft-forge

I have recently forked and cloned a [repositroy](https://github.com/MinecraftForge/ForgeGradle) from GitHub that uses Gradle, but I am unable to execute any Gradle tasks.

It fails on:

```
def process = 'git rev-parse --short HEAD'.execute()
```

with:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\Joseph\Desktop\Minecraft\ObsidianSuite\ForgeGradle\ForgeGradle\build.gradle' line: 286

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'ForgeGradle'.
> Cannot run program "git": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

I am running Windows 10, and have Git working with MinGW. I have set the path variable to include (C:\Program Files\Git\cmd) such that I can run Git from command prompt. The Git command that is called by the build.gradle file executes fine if I run it from the command line, it is just not working when run through the Gradle wrapper.

Any help or advice would be much appreciated; I am able to answer any questions that might help work out what the issue is. Thanks.

EDIT: I normally use Git by running git-bash in the relevant folder rather than git from command prompt.

Comment: Did you just recently add git to the PATH? if so, you will need to restart any programs that are using the PATH so they can use the new one. (restart the IDE)

Comment: @Murf I did a complete reboot after updating the PATH, with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Please, don't call executables from Java/Groovy/Gradle/etc. There are many java/groovy libraries to deal with Git repositories, including [Gradle plugins](https://github.com/ajoberstar/gradle-git)

Comment: Nice comment... I ran into the same problem by just following what Google did in a repo for their Android I/O Schedule app a few years ago. Now I am stuck with exactly this issue... I wonder why they just did this if these plugins are around for so many years?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution, it doesn't provide an answer to why it wasn't working originally, but gives a work around.

I followed this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16614411/5859264) to install GitHub for Windows and changed the old Git path variable to the one the tutorial suggested. Although I don't want to use the GitHub software (I like doing everything via git-bash), at least Gradle is happy with it now.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the same problem.
I am using Android studio here. When gradlew build is executed, `def process = 'git rev-parse --short HEAD'.execute()` returns empty, but there is no problem in local execution.

Solution:
The solution is: modify the jdk path used by gradlew, use java jdk. (Do not use the sdk that comes with android studio)
Screenshot:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvnLC.png)