# Android studio git build error

Tags: git, android-studio

I cloned a new project from GitHub and initialised the build for the first time. I got an error saying:

> cannot run program 'git'
>
> CreateProcess error=2

This is the first time this has happened. All my other projects from GitHub have worked fine. I even checked that the Git path in Android Studio settings is fine and it works. Yet, I am getting this error.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: check the git environment variable path is correct ? see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37093723/how-to-add-an-android-studio-project-to-github)

Comment: what OS are you running on?

Comment: @ThiruShetty as I have said, it works fine with my other projects and I have checked the variable path and confirmed that git works. I am also able to perform VCS operations like fetch, clone etc.

Comment: @antzshrek Windows 10

Comment: @speedster01 check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16614410/android-studio-checkout-github-error-createprocess-2-windows) solved same issue

Comment: @ThiruShetty I have already tried and implemented both the links you have mentioned before posting this question. As I have pointed out to you multiple times now, I have checked that the Git path in Android Studio settings is fine and it works. Furthermore, Git works just fine for all my other projects.